# IndexError: Replacement index 2 out of range for positional args tuple when trying to insert data to sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite

I saw a video where with this piece of code, he inserted the data of his QTableWidget to his sqlite database:

```
#reading the data
def insertDatainDB(self):
global dbConnection
productsIn = [self.inventoryTable.item(row, 0).text() for row in range(self.inventoryTable.rowCount())]
priceIn = [self.inventoryTable.item(row, 1).text() for row in range(self.inventoryTable.rowCount())]
discountIn = [self.inventoryTable.item(row, 2).text() for row in range(self.inventoryTable.rowCount())]
soldIn = [self.inventoryTable.item(row, 3).text() for row in range(self.inventoryTable.rowCount())]
totalSoldIn = [self.inventoryTable.item(row, 4).text() for row in range(self.inventoryTable.rowCount())]
inevntoryIn = [self.inventoryTable.item(row, 5).text() for row in range(self.inventoryTable.rowCount())]

#inserting the data
with self.dbConnection:
    cur = self.dbConnection.cursor()
    cur.execute(""" INSERT INTO products ("producto", "precioActual", "descuentos", "ventasEnLaSemana", "totalVendido", "enInventario"), VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}') """ .format(*productsIn) .format(*priceIn) .format(*discountIn) .format(*soldIn) .format(*totalSoldIn) .format(*inevntoryIn))
```

The problem is on "cur.exeute" and says this: "IndexError: Replacement index 2 out of range for positional args tuple".

Does someone know why this happen? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your use of `.format()`.  Calls to `format()` must contain values for *all* of the format strings, but instead you're trying to chain them together.  You can't do that.

In this specific case, the error is telling you that the first call to `format()` found values for the `{0}` and `{1}` format strings, but not for the `{2}` string.

`'{0} {1} {2}'.format(0,1)` produces the same error.